# Close image by clicking anywhere outside the image

Tags: javascript, html

How can make, when click any where out of image, close image?

My JavaScript is currently like:

```
const allImages = document.querySelectorAll(".images .img");
const lightbox = document.querySelector(".lightbox");
const closeImgBtn = lightbox.querySelector(".close-icon");

allImages.forEach((img) => {
  img.addEventListener("click", () =>
    showLightbox(img.querySelector("img").src)
  );
});

const showLightbox = (imgSrc) => {
  lightbox.querySelector("img").src = imgSrc;
  lightbox.classList.add("show");
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

  document.addEventListener("keydown", closeLightboxOnEsc);
};

const closeLightbox = () => {
  lightbox.classList.remove("show");
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";

  document.removeEventListener("keydown", closeLightboxOnEsc);
};

const closeLightboxOnEsc = (event) => {
  if (event.key === "Escape") {
    closeLightbox();
  }
};

closeImgBtn.addEventListener("click", closeLightbox);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research, search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+close+lightbox+click+outside+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

You could listen on the document and if anything is clicked but inside `.lightbox` you close the lightbox:

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.closest('.lightbox') || closeLightbox());
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest